# python imaplib - error 'unexpected repsonse'

Tags: python-2.7, imaplib

Hi I've suddenly encountered an error using imaplib on some code that worked fine before.

```
import imaplib
m = imaplib.IMAP4('myserver','port')
m.login(r'username','password')
m.select()
```

gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 649, in select
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1070, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 899, in _command_complete
    raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))
imaplib.abort: command: SELECT => unexpected response: '*  1520 EXISTS'
```

I'm not sure what it means. Emails are otherwise coming through fine, and I'm using davmail as a server.

The program in its entirety saves attachments with a certain name in a specific folder.

I've stepped through it and its definitely the `m.select()` that is where its falling over.

This same program worked absolutely fine until recently.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

The log of activity is as follows

```
>>> import imaplib
>>> m = imaplib.IMAP4('server','port')
>>> Debug=4
>>> m.debug
0
>>> m.debug=4
>>> m.debug
4
>>> m.login(r'username','password')
  01:26.55 > HLFI1 LOGIN "username" "password"
  01:30.76 < HLFI1 OK Authenticated
('OK', ['Authenticated'])
>>> m.list()
  01:56.33 > HLFI2 LIST "" *
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Trash/Sent Messages"
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sync Issues/Server Failures"
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sync Issues/Local Failures"
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sync Issues/Conflicts"
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "Sync Issues"
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Junk E-mail"
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Drafts"
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "Trash"
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent"
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Outbox"
  02:00.04 < * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX"
  02:00.04 < HLFI2 OK LIST completed
('OK', ['(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Trash/Sent Messages"', '(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sync Issues/Server Failures"', '(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sync Issues/Local Failures"', '(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sync Issues/Conflicts"', '(\\HasChildren) "/" "Sync Issues"', '(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Junk E-mail"', '(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Drafts"', '(\\HasChildren) "/" "Trash"', '(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent"', '(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Outbox"', '(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX"'])
>>> m.select()
  02:21.37 > HLFI3 SELECT INBOX
  02:30.87 < *  1548 EXISTS
  02:30.87 last 4 IMAP4 interactions:
  00:16.73 < * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 AUTH=LOGIN MOVE] IMAP4rev1 DavMail 4.3.0-2125 server ready
  00:16.73 > HLFI0 CAPABILITY
  00:16.74 < * CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 AUTH=LOGIN MOVE
  00:16.77 < HLFI0 OK CAPABILITY completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 649, in select
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1070, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 899, in _command_complete
    raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))
imaplib.abort: command: SELECT => unexpected response: '*  1548 EXISTS'
```

** UPDATE **

I've now filed a bug at python-dev under

[Bug report on Python](http://bugs.python.org/issue18153)

Where David Murray says the response is non RFC compliant

And a second at davmail sourceforge under

[davmail bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/davmail/bugs/532/)

M guessant says it is necessary for the IMAP keep alive.

I'll keep this updated with developments..

Comment: Was the server upgraded recently?  In isolation, this looks like part of a valid IMAP response string, but maybe it appears out of context, or maybe there is a bug in `imaplib`.  Can you obtain verbose logging of the IMAP session and add to the question, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the space-padded message count in the `RECENT` response is what triggers this.  It is unclear to me whether it should be classified as an error in Python's `imaplib` or in the IMAP server you are using.  I would argue that `imaplib` should be robust against this, regardless of what the spec says.  Perhaps you should file a bug report?

(If you do, please take care to add details about which server is producing this response.  If it is a commercial product with a respectable market share, it is important to fix, whereas of course, if it's your own simple Python server, they might not care.)

Comment: Hi @tripleee haven't been able to find the ite to file imaplib bug reports. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: [bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/) seems to be the place, but if you are using a particular version, maybe file it against their bug tracker and have them raise the issue upstream.  Either way, please follow up here with a pointer to the bug.  See also http://docs.python.org/devguide/  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found the response of the `EXISTS` command is padded by `davmail`, it seems to be when the number of emails is around or over 500.

Acceptable response:

```
  58:24.54 > PJJD3 EXAMINE INBOX
  58:24.77 < * 486 EXISTS
  58:24.78      matched r'\* (?P<data>\d+) (?P<type>[A-Z-]+)( (?P<data2>.*))?' => ('486', 'EXISTS', None, None)
  58:24.78 untagged_responses[EXISTS] 0 += ["486"]
```

Failed response:

```
  57:50.86 > KPFE3 EXAMINE INBOX
  57:51.10 < *  953 EXISTS
  57:51.10 last 0 IMAP4 interactions:
  57:51.10 > KPFE4 LOGOUT
```

Have create a pull request for the `imaplib` library at [github](https://github.com/edwardmbsmith/cpython/pull/1) to account for the issue

To patch your code the `imaplib` allows the regex to be altered, simply add the following to your code:

```py
imaplib.Untagged_status = imaplib.re.compile(br'\*[ ]{1,2}(?P<data>\d+) (?P<type>[A-Z-]+)( (?P<data2>.*))?')
```